# How to put an existing container in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I already have a vue application containerized and running, but how do I put it in docker compose?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app

RUN  npm install @babel/core @babel/node @babel/preset-env nodemon express axios cors mongodb

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

So when I try to put port "4200" it says that I have already the same port running, so how do I put that container inside whole app which will store multiple containers?

This is my docker-compose try:

```
version: '3.8'
services: 
  posts:
    build: ./posts
    ports: 
      - "4200:4200"
```

So this is the visualisation of something that I want to do:

[image]

Comment: Stop and delete your existing container, or press `^C` to stop your local development copy of the application.

Comment: Okay, that's good solution too! Thank you, btw this works but my axios communication between other microservices doesn't work, is it something that is needed in docker compose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change host port in compose

For example:

```
ports: 

  - "4201:4200"
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Another question non-related to this question, if I make the new changes on my dockerized app, will they change? Or I have to repeat the build process?